# Path.getParent() is null

Tags: java, nio

I just encountered behavior I do not understand:

```
Path path = Paths.get("somefile.txt");
System.out.println(path.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(path.getParent());
```

Well, to be honest, I was debugging some code and I evaluated this code on runtime and path was resolved as WindowsPath instance, therefore there was method `getAbsolutePath` available.

When I ran the code, parent was null but absolutePath printed the absolute path. So If the object knows absolute path and there is parent directory why does it return null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to give the complete path /home/username/filename.txt instead somefile.txt

Comment: This sounds good. I just do not understand why WindowsPath has real path information but do not use it.

Comment: @LeosLiterak try `path.getAbsolutePath().getParent()` instead.  Or do what we do, and start with something like `path = path.getAbsolutePath();` so that all operations on `path` are more intuitive.

Answer (score 6):

According to the javadoc, the [Path#getParent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getParent%28%29) method :

> Returns the parent path, or null if this path does not have a parent.

and

> This method does not access the file system; the path or its parent may not exist

This means that `"somefile.txt"` doesn't have a parent path in the context of the root of your application.

Comment: I read javadoc as well but getAbsolutePath does return real path so it does accesses file system.

Comment: I'm talking about `getAbsolutePath()` but about `getParent()` :)